# prove $(a^3+1)(b^3+1)(c^3+1)\ge 8$

Tags: inequality, logarithms, contest-math, lagrange-multiplier, tangent-line-method

let $a,b,c\ge 0$ and such $a+b+c=3$ show that
$$(a^3+1)(b^3+1)(c^3+1)\ge 8$$

**My research**:It seem use Holder inequality,so 
$$(a^3+1)(b^3+1)(c^3+1)\ge (abc+1)^3$$
Use AM-GM
$$abc\le\dfrac{(a+b+c)^3}{27}=1$$
what? then I think  this method is wrong

Comment: @A---B assuming you meant $c=1$, those integers don't satisfy $a+b+c =3$

Comment: since $a+b+c=3$, and why download it?

Comment: Jensen's Inequality would be useful here

Comment: @Hari Shankar $\left(\ln(x^3+1)\right)''=\frac{3x(2-x^3)}{(x^3+1)^3}$ and Jensen does not help here. By the way, we can use the Vasc's LCF Theorem.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg This wouldnt be the first time you have caught me misusing the inequality :). Anyway, its an honour to be corrected by you!

Comment: abc <= 1 means (abc+1)^3 <= 8 <= blahblah is not in any way a contradiction..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(\ln(a^3+1)-\ln2\right)=\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(\ln(a^3+1)-\ln2-\frac{3}{2}(a-1)\right)$.

Let $f(x)=\ln(x^3+1)-\ln2-\frac{3}{2}(x-1)$.

Easy to see that $\min\limits_{[0,2]}f=0$.

Indeed, $f'(x)=\frac{3x^2}{x^3+1}-\frac{3}{2}=\frac{3(1-x)(x^2-x-1)}{2(x^3+1)}$ and since $x_{max}=\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$,

it remains to check that $f(2)>0$, which is true.

Thus, for $\{a,b,c\}\subset[0,2]$ our inequality is proven.

Let $a>2$.

Hence, $\prod\limits_{cyc}(a^3+1)\geq(8+1)\cdot1\cdot1>8$.

Done!

Comment: If you let $a>2$, then there's the stronger fact: $\prod\limits_{cyc}\left(a^3+1\right)\ge \left(a^3+1\right)\cdot 1\cdot 1$ $>(8+1)\cdot1\cdot1=9>8$.

Comment: @user236182 59 and we get $\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^3+1)>8$ again.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x,y,z) = (x^3 +1)(y^3 +1)(z^3 +1)$ subject to the constraint $g(x,y,z) = x + y + z - 3 =0$ and $ x,y,z \ge 0$.

Then using lagrange multipliers we have

- $f_x = 3x^2(y^3 +1)(z^3 +1)= g_x= \lambda$
- $f_y = 3y^2(x^3 +1)(z^3 +1)= g_y = \lambda$
- $f_z = 3z^2(x^3 +1)(y^3 +1)=g_z = \lambda$
- $g(x,y,z) = x + y + z - 3 =0$

From the first three equations we see $x^2(y^3 +1) = y^2(x^3 +1) = z^2(y^3 +1)$. So then $x =z$, since $x, z \ge 0$. Then clearly $x=y=z$, so plugging into our formula for $g$, we see $x=y=z=1$, so $(1,1,1)$ is a critical point.

Now, $f(1,1,1) = 8$. To see this is a minimum, we see $(0,0,3)$ lies on our curve, and $f(0,0,3) = 28 \gt f(1,1,1) = 8.$

We conclude that $(a^3 +1)(b^3 +1)(c^3 +1) \ge 8$.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but do you know it OP knows something about Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: Given he knows about Holder's inequality, I'm fairly sure he knows Lagrange multipliers. If not, this is just but one solution.

Comment: The LM is okay but OP wants to see AM-GM, Cauchy-Schwarz, or Schur or Muirhead inequalities used in the proof. OP seems interested in non-derivative answers.

Comment: It's one way to do it. Maybe someone else can find another one!

Answer (score 1):

WLOG we assume that $(b-1)(c-1)\ge 0$.

By Carlson inequality we have
\begin{aligned}
{[(a^3+1)(b^3+1)(c^3+1)]}^{\frac{1}{3}}= & \;\;[(a^3+1)(1+b^3)(1+c^3)]^{\frac{1}{3}} \\
\ge & \;\;a+bc\\
= & \;\;3-b-c+bc\\
= & \;\;2+(b-1)(c-1)\\
\ge & \;\;2.
\end{aligned}
Done.

Comment: could you give a reference to the Carlson inequality you used here? My impression about Carlson inequality seems different.

Comment: @Yimin Here by Carlson inequality I mean $(x_1+y_1)(x_2+y_2)(x_3+y_3)\ge [(x_1 x_2 x_3)^{\frac{1}{3}}+(y_1 y_2 y_3)^{\frac{1}{3}}]^3$ (Just a special case of Hölder's inequality)

Answer (score 0):

BY Jensen inequality with  $\phi\left(t\right)=\ln(t^3+1)$

$$\phi\left(\frac13\sum_{i=1}^{3}x_i\right)\le \frac13\sum_{i=1}^{3}\phi\left(x_i\right) $$

since $a+b+c= 3$ we get 
$$\ln(2)=\phi\left(1\right)\le \frac13\left(\ln(a^3+1)+\ln(b^3+1)+\ln(c^3+1)\right) $$

hence $$\ln8= 3\ln(2)\le \ln \left((a^3+1)(b^3+1)(c^3+1)\right)$$
that is $$(a^3+1)(b^3+1)(c^3+1)\ge 8$$